# Regex expression with letters before

Tags: java, regex

I would like to add "!"befeore my regex epression. 
I have:

```
TASK PERS asdf

PERS asdf
```

and I would like to use regex and get

```
! TASK PERS asdf

! PERS asdf
```

and I do not know how to write regex expression :( I have tried many time,...but I failed, can You help me please?

java

```
newContent = content.replaceAll("[A-Z]*TASK PERS", "!TASK PERS")
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Why not just `newContent = "! " + content` I don't see any importance of regex here except I don't understand your question

Comment: Are you asking how to add `!` at start of *every* line or only at start of some selected ones? If only selected ones what are criteria of selection?

Comment: To content  I am loading big text file, and in this file I would like to search PERS/TASK PERS and add exclamation mark before PERS/TASK PERS

Comment: Do `PERS/TASK PERS` always appear at start of each line or can they appear in the middle of line? If they can appear in the middle then do you want to place `!` at start of line or *directly* before `PERS/TASK PERS`, or maybe you want to ignore ones in the middle of line?

Comment: It appears in the middle of loaded file, but it is always at the beginning of a line, and I would like to add ```!``` at start of a line

Answer (score 1):

Non-regular-expression methods would be much better for this task, yet if we wish to do with expression, this would likely work:

```
(TASK PERS|PERS)(.*)
```

and replace it with `! $1$2`

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6cE9CG/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(TASK PERS|PERS)(.*)";
final String string = "TASK PERS asdf\n"
     + "PERS asdf\n"
     + "TASK PERS asdf\n"
     + "PERS asdf";
final String subst = "! \\1\\2";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solution is to match start of the line `^` (with [MULTILINE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) flag `(?m)`) and then check if after it there is `PERS` or `TASK PERS`. We can do it with [positive look-ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=...)` which doesn't put text matched by it into match of entire regex, so `PERS` or `TASK PERS` will not be modified.

So your code can look like:

```
//                                ┌ enable MULTILINE option
//                                |  ┌ match start of the line
//                                |  | ┌ ensure that there is PERS|TASK PERS 
//                                ↓  ↓ ↓ after it (after start of the line)
newContent = content.replaceAll("(?m)^(?=PERS|TASK PERS)", "!");
//                                                          ↑
//                                    we can use only ! because `PERS|TASK PERS` 
//                                    will not be part of match so it will 
//                                              not be replaced
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a match with an optional part `(?:TASK )?` for TASK followed by a space and replace with `!` and the match. Add a space if you also want that in the replacement.

As Pshemo points out in his comment, you should make use of the [Multiline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_Multiline) flag. Or use `(?m)` as a modifier at the start of the pattern.

```
newContent = content.replaceAll("^(?:TASK )?PERS\b", "!$0");

^(?:TASK )?PERS\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sC4s9B/2)